# Format NSString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a string like 748973525 now i need to format it like 748-973-525 in Objective C

Comment: Will your string always be a number?

Comment: Will your string always have 9 digits?

Comment: @marc how deleted my post with regards to FAQ. it fullfilled the FAQ, was valid and though it didnt contain ready-made code It'd appreciate if you just deleted partial answers that show a valid approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways of solving this.  We don't have the specifications for the input string; but you could adopt the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *original = @"748973525";
    NSRegularExpression *exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})" 
            options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *new = [exp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:original 
            options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,original.length) 
            withTemplate:@"$1-$2-$3"];
    printf("%s",[new UTF8String]);

    [p release];
}
```

Prints `748-973-525` to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Split your original string using `-[NSString substringWithRange:]` into three parts, say `a`, `b`, and `c`, and combine them again using `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

For example:

```
NSString *s = @"748973525";
NSString 
  *a = [s substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 3)],
  *b = [s substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(3, 3)],
  *c = [s substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(6, 3)];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%@-%@", a, b, c];
```

This will, of course, only work for strings with nine characters or more; if `s` has a length of less than nine, `substringWithRange` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom "Number Formatter" and set the "Grouping Separator" to "-"